# loading Instagram into frame

Tags: html

how to load instagram page into frame.
The code that I wrote below blocks the page of instagram

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.instagram.com"></iframe>
    <button> Start </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: instagram uses the HTTP header `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`, so the web browser will not show the page in a `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: How to bypass HTTP header x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN?